# DAX Measure ignoring DATESBETWEEN filter

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've got 2 tables, one is called "Treatments" and it contains a distinct SessionId on each row, it contains a Treatment Date and a Treatment Classification (Completed or Non Completed)

This table looks something like this

[image]

Separately, I've got a calendar table called "Date" that contains a column called "Date" where each row is a distinct date for the past 3 years. and it also has a column called Date30D which contains the date for 30 days previous, this is calculated the following way.

```
Date30D = CALCULATE(MIN('Date'[Date]), DATEADD('Date'[Date], -30, DAY))
```

So what I am trying to do is calculate a column through a DAX measure that counts for each row on the date table, the number of "Completed" treatments for the past 30 days.

This is my measure

```
Completed Treatments = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(Treatments),
    Treatments[Treatment Status] = "Completed",
    DATESBETWEEN(
        Treatments[Treatment Date],
        'Date'[Date30D],
        'Date'[Date]))
```

The issue is that, it is calculating the number of completed treatments by day, not by month, it is ignoring the DATESBETWEEN condition completely and I don't know why. What can I do to fix this?

[image]

(This is what the column looks like, the results should be way higher, it is just calculating by day)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way to fix this issue.

```
Completed Treatments = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(Treatments),
    Treatments[Treatment Status] = "Completed",
    'Date'[Date] >= EARLIER('Date'[Date30D]) && 'Date'[Date] <= EARLIER('Date'[Date]))
```

the EARLIEST function will filter only by the dates within your row.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:
(for simplicity, I calculated the Count of Completed Treatments first... with a simple filter).

```
Count of Completed Treatments = 
      CALCULATE(
          COUNTROWS('TreatmentsFact'),
          FILTER('TreatmentsFact',[Classification]="Completed")
        )
```

Then all I have to do is adjust the time span...

```
Completed Past 30 Days = 
    CALCULATE([Count of Completed Treatments],
             FILTER('DimDate',
                'DimDate'[Date]>=MAX('DimDate'[Date])-30 &&
                'DimDate'[Date]<='DimDate'[Date])
    )
```